# Consulta parametrizada php salida

Tags: php, mysql

Modificando mis codigos de escuela para añadir parametros, pues no entiendo la documentacion de php y nose como sacar el resultado de la consulta. Desde la tabla privilegio deberia dar 1(administrador) o 2 (secretaría). Help please.

```
  try {

      //Conection papu
      $cnn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbautomotora");

      if (!$cnn) {
        die("Conexion Fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }else {
        $nombre_usuario = $_POST['txt_nombre_admin']; //Nombre del usuario
        $contraseña_usuario = $_POST['txt_password_admin'];//Contraseña usuario
        $privilegio_usuario = $_POST['sel_privilegio']; //Nivel del usuario

        $sql = mysqli_prepare($cnn,"SELECT privilegio FROM usuarios WHERE (nombre = ? and password = ? and privilegio = ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "ssi", $nombre_usuario, $contraseña_usuario, $privilegio_usuario);

        $rs = mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
          //PARAMETRIZADO HASTA AQUI
        if ($rs==0) {
          //No hay dato vuelve a la pagina
        }else {
              while ($fila = mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)) {
                  $nivel = $fila["privilegio"];
                  echo $nivel; //Quiero que me devuelva la consulta como se hace help
              }


          }
      }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      //Errores de excepcion
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me respondo solo, es muy noob la pregunta asi que si me dicen la borro. 
la funcion `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($consulta,$variable)` permite vincular una variable por `fila(?)` del resultado del `while`, desde ahi puedes guardarlas y manipularlas a gusto.

```
if ($rs==0) {
      //No hay dato vuelve a la pagina
    }else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql, $privilegio); 
          while ($fila = mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)) {
              printf($privilegio);

          }


    }
  }
```

Comment: no tienes por que borrarla todos los aportes valen igual, lo que si te pido es que le des editar y seas mas claro explicando como esto resuelve tu priblema  para que recibas mas votos positivos por parte de la comunidad y sirva como referente a otros usuarios